# Parsing date string with different dateformats

Tags: java, parsing, date-format

I am trying to parse date strings, my problem is that those strings can have different dateformats depends on if they talk about today, tomorrow or another day.

- If they talk about today event the format is like this:   20:45
- If they talk about tomorrow event the format is: tomorrow 20: 45
- And if they talk about another day the format is: May 10 2016

So I would like to know if I can parse the three of them with the same DateFormat, if not what will be the best way.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d ' de' MMMM ' de' yyyy", locale);
```

Comment: Which Java Version do you use?

Comment: no, you cannot parse them with the same DateFormat instance, since this expects the value to be parsed to have a given format. If you're sure these are the only formats you can get, you could first check for the String's length == 5 if it's today, afterwards check if the String includes "tomorrow" and if none of them were true, you could format it with DateFormat.

Answer (score -1):

You cant use the same SimpleDateFormat to parse all types, and wont be a good practice neither, not readable and more complex not adding any special value, i would try something like this:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat formatHHMM = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
private static final SimpleDateFormat formatOther = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");

private static String convertDate(Date curDate) {
    if (isToday(curDate)) {
        return formatHHMM.format(curDate);
    }
    else if (isTomorrow(curDate)) {
        return "Tomorrow " + formatHHMM.format(curDate);
    }
    return formatOther.format(curDate);
}

private static boolean isToday(Date curDate) {
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    return today.equals(curDate);
}

private static boolean isTomorrow(Date curDate) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
    return tomorrow.equals(curDate);
}
//Check the code with this
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Date curDate = new Date();
    System.out.println( convertDate(curDate));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println( convertDate(tomorrow));

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 15);
    Date other = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println( convertDate(other));
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted a solution to **parse** different date formats, not to **format**.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to parse the 3 formats with the same formatter. Although it may be possible to parse the first two with only one formatter, the difference of meaning (today or tomorrow) would imply a different logic, which can't be obtained with a single formatter.

I suggest you to handle each case separately, trying one after another:

```
    try {
        return LocalDate
                .now()
                .atTime(LocalTime.parse(date));
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        try {
            return LocalDate
                    .now()
                    .plusDays(1)
                    .atTime(LocalTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'tomorrow' HH:mm")));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e1) {
            return LocalDate
                    .parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH))
                    .atStartOfDay();
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure about the clarity of the control flow, though. If the the number of input formats grows, a refactor into something clearer may be required.

Comment: Well, I don't like control flow by exception catching, but that is not your fault (here forced by API-limitations). Anyway, the performance will suffer, that is sure.

Comment: I don't think add the logic with the exception flow is a clear solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (DateFormat.charAt(0).isDigit() && DateFormat.charAt(1).isDigit() && DateFormat.charAt(2).isLetterOrDigit()==false  .... {
new String SimpleDateFormat= '15.03.2016';
else {

if (DateFormat.charAt(0).isLetter('t') &&  DateFormat.charAt(1).isLetter('o') &&   and so on 
 { SimpleDateFormat='16.03.2016'
```

and you may change the condition on 1 by 1 character to match all your type of data formats

Comment: Please, provide at least to the OP a compilable code.